# How to dynamically add an ng-repeat attribute to an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to dynamically add an `ng-repeat` attribute to an element?
If so, how?

**EDIT**:

I was trying to create a component that will use a custom template inside it for each items on its list.

Example

```
<custom-component>
  <item-template>
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <item-template>
<custom-component>
```

Then the result shall be

```
<custom-component>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">(the template)</li>
  </ul>
</custom-component>
```

So I tried to just set the innerHTML of the ul to a string like so:

```
ul.innerHtml = "<li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">{{item.name}}</li>"
```

Comment: What do you mean dynamically ?

Comment: setting the innerHTML of an element with, for example: `<li ng-repeat>`

Comment: looks like you're coming from jQuery background.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question here to accurately understand what you are trying to achieve.  Normally, modifying the DOM directly isn't a practice that is used in AngularJs unless absolutely necessary, and using an `ng-repeat` to iterate through an array with a single element is a perfectly acceptable approach, so "dynamically" adding the tag seems like a sub-optimal approach.

Comment: After your recent edit, it's even less obvious why you would want to add the ng-repeat "dynamically".  Simply define the template for the component, and use the list as if it is always going to be a list, and if a single element is passed in, just iterate it once.

Comment: I tried to do it this way so that it is possible to change the template of the list items from the html itself.

Comment: again, why are you trying to modify the `innerHtml`?  you aren't really showing the code you are using to define your component, or where that `ul.innerHtml` call is in your code, but it feels like if the component is structured correctly, it's not necessary.  What does "change the template of the list items from the html itself" mean?  why would the template need to be changed?  It's still not really clear what you are *actually* trying to solve;  This is feeling more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619) the more you try to explain it.

Comment: I'm creating a component like this https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

The autocomplete component has a template for the list items

Comment: ok so you pass a template in, and you iterate through the template for each element.  again, why would you need to "dynamically change" the template?

Comment: I tried to insert an element with ng-repeat and the bindings on the $onInit of my component. it doesn't work, I just don't know how to pass that template to the ng-repeat element. That's why I tried to create and insert one on the $onInit

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be showing an element which have ng-repeat depending on a condition that you can change dynamically:

```
<div ng-switch="dynamicCondition">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-repeat="item in items">Element which have ng-repeat</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="false">Element without ng-repeat</div>
</div>
```